# PostgreSQL view errors

Tags: postgresql

I am having an issue with creating a view in psql and Centos.

I have a file that contains a query. It looks like this

[image]

when I do

```
psql -d cjones< order_tester.sql
```

It runs correctly.

I then try to create a view and this is where I have an issue.

[image]

Unless I am missing something that is the same text but it is tellin gme that there is a column id issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: A view has to have unique identifiers for its column names.  But when you're just running a query there isn't such an issue, the output is just labeled conveniently (and those labels aren't necessarily proper column names, IIRC).

Comment: This is all test stuff anyways... so how do you fix that then if you need two id fields..

Comment: Instead of `SELECT *`, you reference each column and give the second and third `ID` column a unique alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JayC and JNevill gave you your answer in the comments. You can't have two columns with names that are the same when creating views.

They said that you can't do a `SELECT *`, but rather would have to do something like

```
SELECT con.id AS contact_id, cust.id AS customer_id, etc.
```

Something that I'd like to add is that if you want to be able to use `SELECT *` for creating a view, then when you create your tables you can avoid generic terms like `id` and instead your `contacts` table could have a `contact_id` column and your `customers` table could have a `customer_id` column. Then you don't run into the issue.

Comment: I wanted to just add a comment up top, but apparently I don't have enough reputation points to do that yet :P So to add my comment I summarized what they said in addition to adding my comment so that it's not out of context.